# In Elasticsearch how to get all mapped fields when we search for a document?

Tags: elasticsearch

For Example I have an Elasticsearch Index and Type Mapping as below:

```
PUT /index
{"mappings": {
"type": {
    "properties":{
    "title":{
    "type":"string"
    } ,
    "name":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "warning":{
        "type":"string"
          }
       }
   }
```

}
 }
and i have one document like

```
Document 1: {"type":"type text","name":"name text"}
```

now when I query for Document 1 since I have not indexed `warning` field but I have created the mapping for it I need to get `warning` value as null. That is my response should be `{" type":"type text","name":"name text","warning": null}` Is this possible in Elasticsearch and or while indexing does I need the map that `warning` field as null or I am missing anything else. Please help. I am using Elasticsearch version 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch gives you back exactly what you indexed (in JSON format exactly your initial document), so you need to explicitly index `"warning":null` so that you can get back `"warning":null`.